# Why did Amara (Darkness) ward herself against Him (God)?

Tags: plot-explanation, supernatural

In *Supernatural*, since Amara matured she is finding Him to settle scores. She is trying to get the attention of God.

To call/get the attention of Him she has

- Killed many people.
- Prays in church.
- Killed people in the church.

Also when she catches Lucifer she told him that she will torture him because he is a favourite of God and he will come to save him.

From this, it is clear that Amara wants to meet Him (The God/Chuck).

But in S11 E21 Chuck (God) says that

> She's warded herself specifically against me.

Why did Amara (darkness) ward herself if she is desperately trying to find him?

Answer (score 3):

She's not "desperately" trying to "find him," she's trying to *get revenge* for having been sealed away all those millennia.  She was provoking him because she wanted a showdown, but she also wanted that showdown to happen on *her terms,* when *she* was ready for it.

God is (supposedly) omniscient - barring plot-armored warding, of course.  Without the wards, God would presumably have been aware of her exact location the moment she became free, or if not then, certainly as soon as she started killing people.  Then He could come after her whenever it was good for *Him.* In particular, IIRC, Amara needed some time at the start of the season to regain her full power - if God could have found her in that period, He could have shut her back up before she had a chance to get going on her revenge scheme.

Comment: I am not talking about starting episodes. I think she is ready for God when she caught Lucifer in S11 E20. Because she said to Lucifer in S11 E21" End your suffering, Lucifer. Call out to him. Beg him to save you."

Comment: @CRDave The bit about early episodes was an aside, the main point remains the same throughout the season - she wants to confront God on her terms, not His.  If she wasn't warded against Him, then God would know Amara was with Lucifer, and would be able to prepare for facing her before coming to Lucifer's rescue.  By warding herself, she keeps her presence (or at least her exact location) a secret, the better to facilitate getting the drop on God.

Comment: If so why She ask Lucifer to Call Him or Pray to Him in church? Is like calling someone to meet but not saying where. If She just want to meet when She want (On her term) than She suppose to find Him not Calling Him.

Comment: @CRDave She wants Him to come find *Lucifer.*  She *doesn't want* Him to know that *she's there* waiting to ambush Him when He arrives.